# Is there such a thing for Django as there is Heroku for Ruby on Rails

Tags: python, django, heroku

Is there a cloud based development for Django, such as there is cloud based development and hosting environment for Ruby / [heroku](http://heroku.com/)

Answer (score 16):

**[ep.io](http://www.ep.io/)** provides WSGI hosting Heroku style.  It's from [Andrew Godwin](http://www.aeracode.org/) of [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) fame.  From their website:

> This is ep.io, the hosted WSGI hosting and deployment solution. We take your Django, Flask, Pylons or other WSGI code, run all the annoying hosting parts for you, and make sure everything's redundant and backed up.  In return, we bill you only for the processing time and bandwidth you actually use - we'll even give you detailed analytics of when and where those resources are being used. However, we're currently in a closed beta, so this is only available to those we invite

They support PostgreSQL and Redis. They have a client you download to deploy from the command line, or you can push to them via git or mercurial.  They have a good amount of documentation, but I just recently started using them and haven't pushed a deployment yet so I have no idea of how well the service works yet.

**[Gondor](http://gondor.io/)** is from the [Eldarion](http://eldarion.com/) guys (founder of the company is also founder of [pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/)).  They support:

> > - revision control via git or mercurial
> > - dependency management using pip
> > - database migrations via South or nashvegas
> > - full backups of your entire application
> > - asynchronous and scheduled task execution
> > - full-text search using Solr and django-haystack
> > - caching via memcached or redis

From the survey they have you take when you get a beta account, it seems like they're looking to host massive traffic sites.  The survey actually made me wonder how expensive the service is going to be after beta.

Comment: Ok...I pushed an app onto ep.io (a pinax based app, not hello world)  The process was pretty simple and easy.  redeployment is a single command.  They're going to support SSL soon.  I'm pretty happy with it so far.

Comment: Note that ep.io and gondor.io are both UK-based firms.  I heard at DjangoCon that one or both are starting some hosting on American servers but if its coming from UK there may be a bit of transatlantic lag.

Comment: Another update: ep.io is shutting down.  See my post on Heroku below.

Comment: Sad to see ep.io go.  I may try Heroku or go back to VPS for the time being.

Answer (score 15):

[Heroku itself is now for Django](http://news.heroku.com/news_releases/heroku-announces-major-new-version-celadon-cedar-includes-new-process-model-full-nodejs-).  It supports Django with the new Cedar "run anything" release.

I now use Heroku for a few django projects.  Setup, including adding a postgres DB and deployment is straight-forward, fast, and free or cheap for small projects.   I use and recommend AWS S3 (via django-storages) to host static & uploaded files, and running gunicorn if you're using Heroku in production, all of which is pretty simple to setup.  Heroku's own documentation for its support for python & django is pretty good.  See:

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django

it was sufficient for me, and should get you there and beyond.

Answer (score 3):

[Djangy](https://www.djangy.com/) seems to be similar. I used neither, so I can't say how similar they are. Djangy only supports MySQL as a database, which is kind of a deal breaker for me.

/edit: as Zolomon says, Djangy closed its doors. I'll recommend [RJBrady](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064029/is-there-such-a-thing-for-django-as-there-is-heroku-for-ruby-on-rails/5125546#5125546)'s answer for some serious upvoting.

Comment: Django seems great! But read on their site theyre still on private beta.

Comment: Too bad they just shut down. http://blog.djangy.com/2011/02/27/final-djangy-newsletter/

Answer (score 2):

I just found out about [DotCloud.com](http://www.dotcloud.com/)! Seems like they will support a customizable stack!

Comment: yea, they have a bunch of components. Even php, ruby blabla

Answer (score 1):

google app engine might do what you want - take a look at it here http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/django.html

Comment: Except that it is not 'strictly' Django

Comment: @sebpiq: the full Django stack runs on GAE.

Comment: Really ??? Even all the things in 'contrib' ? 'auth' ? 'admin' ? 'db.models.Model' ?

Comment: App Engine doesn't support the full Django ORM experience yet. There are projects that try to make most of the ORM work (e.g. http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine) but you still have to consider the limitations of App Engine's data store (e.g. no joins). There is a recent development that may bring the full Django experience to App Engine, though: http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers/browse_thread/thread/eee872b03286075e#

Comment: -1. I had a little disappointment with using GAE. Yes it is super easy to use, super fast to deploy, free, etc, etc ... But I had a whole working website in Django, and I had to refactor lots of stuff to have it working with gae... just cause I couldn't find any other free hosting. So 2 -1, because it is certainly not so easy as heroku.

Comment: @sebpiq: what did you expect from free hosting?

Comment: @Rafe Kettler: Same as heroku :)

Answer (score 1):

You could check out [DjangoZoom](http://www.djangozoom.com/): "turn your django code into a live, public app in five minutes" on cloud servers.  You can currently request an invite for the beta version.

Answer (score 1):

I think Graham has them all here http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2011/01/awesome-year-for-python-web-hosting.html

Answer (score 1):

30loops.net is another contender, still in private beta though... Seems a lot of movement is going on in the Python hosting space!

Answer (score 0):

See also this answers

- [Quora: Is there anything like Heroku
  I can use for a Python site (other
  than Google App Engine)](http://www.quora.com/Is-there-anything-like-Heroku-I-can-use-for-a-Python-site-other-than-Google-App-Engine)
- [Quora:
  What is the Heroku equivalent for
  Django applications?](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-Heroku-equivalent-for-Django-applications)

Answer (score -1):

[Media Temple](http://mediatemple.net/) has Django grid containers starting at $20/month.